# Complement of a divisor in an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a domain, not necessarily noetherian or normal, let $X = {\rm Spec}(A)$ and let $U\subseteq X$ be the complement of a prime divisor of $X$. Is it possible that $\mathcal O_U(U) = \mathcal O_X(X)$?

Comment: What is a prime divisor for you? I guess just a height one prime?